# Can't bind ngModel.errors in condition ngSwitchCase

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel, ngmodel, ng-switch

Can't bind `ngModel.errors` in condition of `*ngSwitchCase`.
But if i do this on `*ngIf`, it's work fine for me. 
I wan't make a structure of displaying different's error's in condition of `*ngSwitchCase`. 
[StackBlitz sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-hr1uzx?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&template=node&title=Angular%20Starter)

I tried different variations of `*ngSwitchCase="name.errors?.required"`, but the only solution that works for me is `*ngIf="name2.errors?.required"`.
But I want to make 4 or more error conditions, and I think it would be more correct and readable to do it in `*ngSwitchCase` conditions, but after starting to learn Angular, I can't understand why this directive doesn't work.
Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ngSwitch` with the condition value as `true` to create multiple `if else` statements like below!

If the case is true, it will get displayed!

Since minLength has an object like `{ "minlength": { "requiredLength": 5, "actualLength": 4 } }` when the error is present we can use `!!name.errors?.minlength` to convert the value to a boolean and display the error!

```
<div [ngSwitch]="true">
  <div class="error" *ngSwitchCase="name.errors?.required">The name is required</div>
  <div class="error" *ngSwitchCase="!!name.errors?.minlength">Minimum length of a name is 5!</div>
</div>
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-xr4rfv?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&template=node&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: Thanks, this solution is worked well. But, can u explain why my condition doesn't work with `ngSwitch = ngModel.errors` and `ngSwitchCase=" 'required' "`?